# Gmail Custom Dropdown menu

Tags: gmail

I'd like to know if it is possible to code a Dropdown menu within Gmail with predefined answers. I KNOW you have canned responses and I use them, but I don´t want to configure all the canned responses for all the user in our Google Apps domain..

I just want to know if it is possible, I'm not coding I´m just researching on this subject.

Comment: With Apps Script, you cannot modify the Gmail interface.It is possible through contextual gadgets https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/contextual_gadgets

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [GMailr](https://github.com/jamesyu/gmailr/) - it may provide you with a starting point.